# Running Spark on YARN on single node

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm learning a bit of Data Science and I'm trying to discover and understand the various tools related to it.

So far I have a working installation of Hadoop 2.8.0 on Mac OS and now I'd like to make Spark 2.1.1 work too. I know that Spark doesn't necessarily need the Hadoop environment to work, but I also know that making it run over YARN can be useful in order to share data with other applications.

After reading different guides and suggestions online, this is what I have done:

- In Hadoop configuration files, I added in **yarn-site.xml**:

  ```
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
      <value>localhost</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
      <value>localhost:8030</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
      <value>localhost:8032</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
      <value>localhost:8088</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
      <value>localhost:8031</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
      <value>localhost:8033</value>
  </property>
  ```
- In Spark configuration files, I added in **spark-env.sh**:

  ```
  export SPARK_MASTER_IP=localhost
  export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
  export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=800m
  export SPARK_WORKER_ISTANCES=1
  export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
  export SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES=1
  export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
  ```

Now, after starting Hadoop with `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh` and `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh`, if I try to launch:

```
sudo spark-shell --master yarn
```

(which should be the way to make Spark run over Yarn, if I understand correctly), after a *very long* time, I get the following error:

```
17/06/09 14:55:44 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.ConnectException: Call From Alessandro.local/192.168.2.1 to 0.0.0.0:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor8.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getNewApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getNewApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:96)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
    ... 69 more
17/06/09 14:55:44 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe it's something obvious, but I'm new to this and I need some help.

Comment: Post your `hdfs-site.xml` or `fs.default.Name` in `hdfs-site.xml`

Comment: I don't have a `fs.default.Name` in `hdfs-site.xml`, I just have `dfs.replication` with value `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 0.0.0.0 address in the exception points to the fact that spark-shell is not configured to pick up the address of YARN resource-manager. (Refer [this](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused))

Spark picks up the address of YARN ResourceManager from HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR. In your case, I would suspect that HADOOP_CONF_DIR is not set properly. Just a hunch. Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed the HADOOP_CONF_DIR to `/opt/hadoop/hadoop/etc/hadoop` and this exception disappeared, but I got a new one that after some hours I still can't resolve. Should I open another question or change this one?

Comment: I think you should open a new question.